# Running a WPF app from Command Line "Open With option" will cause it not to recognize relative pathes

Tags: c#, wpf

When I run my app using "open with" option from the windows context menu, the app won't find files or folders in the same directory as the exe

```
 var environmentMapPath = Path.Combine(
     "IncludeResources",
     "EnvironmentMaps",
     defaultEnv
 );

 if (File.Exists(environmentMapPath))
 {
     MessageBox.Show($"{environmentMapPath}");
     EnvironmentMap = new TextureModel(environmentMapPath);
 }
```

here I am attempting to get an image file from the folder `"IncludeResources"` in the same directory as the exe, normally when running using the visual studio debugger or using the executable .exe, the code will work as expected.

but when using "open with-my app-" <on the file type that my app deals with> the `File.Exists(environmentMapPath)`   check will return `false`   and the Message Box will not appear

```
  void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
  {
      var StudioView = new StudioViewModel();
      StudioWindow studioWindow = new StudioWindow(StudioView);
     
      this.MainWindow = studioWindow;
      if (e.Args.Length > 0)
      {
          string filePath = e.Args[0];
          studioWindow.Loaded += (s, args) =>
          {
              WindowLoadedWithCommandLine(s, new CommandLineEventArgs(filePath));
          };
      }
      else
      {
          studioWindow.Loaded += (s, args) =>
          {
              WindowLoaded(s, args);
          };
      }

      studioWindow.Show();
  }
```

I can fix it with this line
`string fullPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, environmentMapPath);`

but this means i would have to update all of the relative pathes to inclued the base directory
is there a better way ?

Comment: Any relative path will be relative to the [current directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory). That is _not_ necessarily the directory containing the executable, and highly varies depending on how you launch it. In my experience, it's a bad idea to rely on that.

Comment: In general it may make sense to have image files embedded into the application's assembly instead of separate files. Set their Build Action to Resource instead of Content. and load them by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf).

Comment: You can also add file resources to your project. This is a .resx file. Double clicking it opens the resource editor that allows to to ad string, icons, files etc. For example, when creating a MyResources.resx file and you add an example.txt file via the resource editor, you can simply reference the file using the generated static resource wrapper `MyResources.example` what would directly return the content of the file.